# Can Events in Excel be registered without a button click?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to create events that are registered when the Excel add-in is first loaded up. I'm not sure how to get around this since I've only seen examples where they are registered with a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the handler registration in the `Office.onReady` or `Office.initialize` method. For an example, see [Change the state in response to an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands#change-the-state-in-response-to-an-event).

Comment: Thank you, I was also wondering if it's possible to register an Event when Excel itself is first loaded up?

Comment: No, an add-in can't be running before Excel has completed loading so it can't handle that event.